# CMake Error 2 when trying to build an apk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android, cmake

When I try to build an APK with CMake on Ubuntu, it says that it failed to sign and gives me an Error 2. Im trying to build DualBootPatcher, if this is necessary.

```
[  9%] File signing target 'sign_prebuilt_exfat_arm64-v8a'
-- Signing: /home/simon/DualBootPatcher/build/thirdparty/prebuilts/exfat/1.3.0-1/arm64-v8a/bin/mount.exfat
/home/simon/DualBootPatcher/build/thirdparty/prebuilts/exfat/1.3.0-1/arm64-v8a/bin/mount.exfat: Failed to open input file
139786185960320:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:74:fopen('/home/simon/DualBootPatcher/build/thirdparty/prebuilts/exfat/1.3.0-1/arm64-v8a/bin/mount.exfat','rb')
139786185960320:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:81:
CMake Error at /home/simon/DualBootPatcher/build/cmake/SignFiles.cmake:22 (message):
  Failed to sign:
  /home/simon/DualBootPatcher/build/thirdparty/prebuilts/exfat/1.3.0-1/arm64-v8a/bin/mount.exfat


thirdparty/CMakeFiles/sign_prebuilt_exfat_arm64-v8a.dir/build.make:57: recipe for target 'thirdparty/CMakeFiles/sign_prebuilt_exfat_arm64-v8a' failed
make[2]: *** [thirdparty/CMakeFiles/sign_prebuilt_exfat_arm64-v8a] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:91: recipe for target 'thirdparty/CMakeFiles/sign_prebuilt_exfat_arm64-v8a.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [thirdparty/CMakeFiles/sign_prebuilt_exfat_arm64-v8a.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can anyone help me with this? I dont know whats wrong

Comment: It tells you **exactly** what is wrong `/home/simon/DualBootPatcher/build/thirdparty/prebuilts/exfat/1.3.0-1/arm64-v8a/bin/mount.exfat: Failed to open input file`

Comment: Im new to this, I still dont know how to fix this. In this directory is no file, its just an empty folder